# Script task failed without going inside Try & Catch block

Tags: c#, error-handling, ssis, try-catch

Here is the brief explanation for my script task in SSIS.

1. Read/Write variable `LOGERROR`, and it does exist in the `Variables` panel with `string` type.
2. Inside the script, C# code:

   ```
   try
     {
      ...  //what here does is to iterate a folder and move all of them to another folder, codes here are working correctly 
      Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
       }
   catch(Exception e)
     {
               Variables lockedVariables = null;

               Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("User::LOGERROR", ref lockedVariables);

               lockedVariables["User::LOGERROR"].Value = e.ToString();

               lockedVariables.Unlock();

               Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;
     }
   ```
3. The reason that I manually control the writes of the variable is that the same variable `LOGERROR` was added to the `Event Handler` for the same purpose of `Point 4`.
4. I direct the `Failure` to another `Execute SQL task`, which is trying to insert `LOGERROR` (Should contain the exception details) into an underlying table.
   **My questions:**
   Sometimes the SSISPackage failed at above task (not always, but at almost the same time every day, may have conflicts with the other jobs?) for not any apparent reasons (at least for now). That's why I would like to track what exactly the issue is, but if I query the target logging table. The details does not show anything, just empty.

And, I have a general logging task in `Event Handler` that logged all the message when task ran with errors. And that message shows nothing but `Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.`

Did I miss something when trying to log `LOGERROR`? Because it seems for me that the script did not go into the `Try & Catch`, just failed directly, otherwise it should store the `Exception` details. (Please correct me if I am wrong). Or, how could I track the error details?

Comment: _"Dts.VariableDispenser.LockOneForWrite("User::LOGERROR", ref lockedVariables);"_ I suspect `lockedVariables` _could_ be null after execution of this line? Thus throwing an exception inside your catch block as soon as you try to use it ...

Comment: Probably the code inside your catch is raising an exception and you assume the exception is not catched.  Comment all the catch content except the `Dts.TaskResult` line and check if something changes.

Comment: ty guys for the comments, testing..

Comment: I don't think `e.ToString()` is what you want.   It's probably something more like `e.Message.ToString()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigations, I think the issue was caused by `SQL Server Agent failed to access the shared folder during certain time frame`.

Possible solution to my questions:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/988207fe-5a25-4da7-a8df-a38fada703da/ssis-script-task-exception-has-been-thrown-by-target-of-invocation?forum=sqlintegrationservices